# Conecto no banco mas os valores não altera quando dou UPDATE MYSQL Qt C++

Tags: mysql, c++, qt, crud, qtgui

Os dados são carregados na tabela, ai eu altero os dados na tabela, quando clico no botão para atualizar, consigo pegar os dados(ate mesmo as alterações) e guardar na variável, mas parece que quando entro na query sql nada acontece. Preciso poder atualizar os dados da tabela assim que alterar algo e clicar no botão atualizar.

Conexão com o banco(ok):

```js
void ConectaBanco()
{
    //Variavel do tipo DataBase
    QSqlDatabase db;

    //Conexao com o MYSQL
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

    //Servidor que vai receber o DB (padrão do server local)
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");

    //Porta que vai conectar com o DB (por padrão vai ser 3306)
    db.setPort(3306);

    //Seleciona o banco de dados
    db.setDatabaseName("cursos");

    //Usuario do BD
    db.setUserName("root");

    //Caso tenha senha no mysql
    //db.setPassword();

    //Teste de conexao
    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Sucesso ao abrir a conexão";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

Função atualizar:

```js
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int fila = 0;
    ConectaBanco();
    int CdAluno = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,0)).toInt();
    QString NmAluno = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,1)).toString();
    QString NmCurso = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,2)).toString();
    QString NmEscola = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,3)).toString();


    QSqlQuery query("UPDATE matricula set NmAluno= '"+NmAluno+"', "
                                         "NmCurso= '"+NmCurso+"', "
                                         "NmEscola='"+NmEscola+"' "
                                         "WHERE CdMatricula='"+CdAluno+"'");
    query.exec();

}
```

Quando debugo e coloco o mouse em cima do da string UPDATE aparece a seguinte mensagem: no much value
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como resolver o problema e conseguir alterar os dados perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função atualizar deveria estar com o campo CdMatricula no formato string para a query reconhecer o codigo:

```js
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ConectaBanco();
    int linha = 0;
    QString CdAluno = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(linha,0)).toString();
    QString NmAluno = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(linha,1)).toString();
    QString NmCurso = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(linha,2)).toString();
    QString NmEscola = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(linha,3)).toString();

    qDebug()<<CdAluno<<NmAluno<<NmCurso<<NmEscola;

    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("UPDATE `matricula` SET `NmAluno` = '"+NmAluno+"', "
                                         "`NmCurso` = '"+NmCurso+"', "
                                         "`NmEscola` = '"+NmEscola+"'"
                                         " WHERE `matricula`.`CdMatricula` = '"+CdAluno+"'");



    if(query.exec())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Query executada com sucesso!";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Erro ao executar a query";
    }

    //atualiza a tabela automaticamente
    on_btnCarga_clicked();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de concatenar a string de query, tente algo assim:

```
#include <QVariant>
...
...

QSqlQuery query
query.prepare("UPDATE matricula SET NmAluno= ?, NmCurso= ?, NmEscola=? WHERE CdMatricula=?");

query.addBindValue(NmAluno);
query.addBindValue(NmCurso);
query.addBindValue(NmEscola);
query.addBindValue(CdAluno);

if( ! query.exec()) {
    qDebug() << "Erro ao executar query!!";
}
```

E cuidado, o que está no seu método `void ConectaBanco()`, só pode sr executado uma única vez. Se você adicionar um BD duas vezes, você vai ter um erro de conexão duplicada(como tá aparecendo aí na sua telinha de output do Qt Creator) e o seu código pode não funcionar como você espera. Se eu fosse você criaria uma classe auxiliar pra manejar as conexões ao MySql.